# Running Protractor Tests in Jenkins (CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise)

Tags: angular, jenkins, protractor, continuous-integration, cloudbees

In the spirit of continuous integration, I am attempting to add my newly written Protractor tests to the execution shell of my Jenkins build. The goal is to have Jenkins run these tests before it continues on to start up a new dev instance (if build was successful).

Locally, I can just run `ng e2e` and my tests will run successfully. But when I add `ng e2e` to my execution shell on Jenkins (CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise), it compiles the angular project successfully and then fails when using ChromeDriver. I don't have a full understanding of how ChromeDriver is used by Protractor and am having a hard time troubleshooting because of it.

- protractor 5.4.2
- webdriver-manager 12.1.5
- chromedriver 75.0.3770.140

**Previous successful Jenkins config execution shell**

```
npm install
ng build --prod
... docker build / docker push commands...
```

**New unsuccessful Jenkins config execution shell**

```
npm install
ng e2e
ng build --prod
... docker build / docker push commands...
```

**Jenkins Console Output**

```
+ npm install
added 28 packages from 35 contributors, updated 5 packages and 
audited 29058 packages in 10.602s
found 424 vulnerabilities (11 low, 8 moderate, 405 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
+ ng e2e
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2019-07-25T20:15:33.163Z
Hash: 30985cbe876fe6845e83
Time: 32115ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 1.23 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 241 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 848 kB  [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 596 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 11.4 MB [initial] [rendered]
[13:15:33] I/file_manager - creating folder /apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium
[13:15:33] I/config_source - curl -o/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wdm｣[39m: Compiled successfully.
 [13:15:34] I/downloader - curl -o/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_75.0.3770.140.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.90/chromedriver_linux64.zip
[13:15:34] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_75.0.3770.140.zip
[13:15:34] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_75.0.3770.140
[13:15:35] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:15:35] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[13:15:35] E/launcher - unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=75.0.3770.90 (a6dcaf7e3ec6f70a194cc25e8149475c6590e025-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1003}),platform=Linux 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64 x86_64)
[13:15:35] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=75.0.3770.90     (a6dcaf7e3ec6f70a194cc25e8149475c6590e025-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1003}),platform=Linux 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse     (/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse     (/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response     (/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession     (/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession     (/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at Direct.getNewDriver     (/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:77:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser     (/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then     (/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled     (/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done     (/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch     (/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle     (/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
[13:15:35] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
An unexpected error occurred: undefined
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

**protractor.conf.js**

```
    exports.config = {
      specs: [
        './tests/testComponent.component.e2e-spec.ts'
      ],
      capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
          args: ["--headless", "--window-size=1600x1000"]
        }
      },
      directConnect: true,
      framework: 'jasmine',
      jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 10000,
      }
    ...
    }
```

I've tried adding

```
"postInstall":  "./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager 
update"
```

to `package.json`, but that results in

```
+ npm install

> front-end-ui@0.0.0 postinstall /apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder
> ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update

(node:17926) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_75.0.3770.140.zip'
(node:17926) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[12:26:18] I/update - selenium standalone: file exists /apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
[12:26:18] I/update - selenium standalone: selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar up to date
[12:26:19] I/update - geckodriver: file exists /apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.24.0.tar.gz
[12:26:19] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.24.0.tar.gz
[12:26:19] I/update - geckodriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.24.0
[12:26:19] I/update - geckodriver: geckodriver-v0.24.0 up to date
audited 29199 packages in 10.448s
found 424 vulnerabilities (11 low, 8 moderate, 405 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
+ ng e2e
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2019-07-29T19:26:52.894Z
Hash: 53611fbe157aca9a2c99
Time: 28684ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 1.23 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 241 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 848 kB  [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 596 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 11.4 MB [initial] [rendered]
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wdm｣[39m: Compiled successfully.
(node:17940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_75.0.3770.140.zip'
(node:17940) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[IT HANGS HERE UNTIL I CANCEL]
Build was aborted
```

When I tested these steps locally, I do see `chromedriver_75.0.3770.140.zip` in the expected location.

I have also tried specifying `chromeDriver` in `protractor.conf.js`

```
chromeDriver: '../node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_75.0.3770.140'
```

I have also tried removing `directConnect: true` but the result is the same:

```
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wdm｣[39m: Compiled successfully.
(node:17940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_75.0.3770.140.zip'
(node:17940) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[IT HANGS HERE UNTIL I CANCEL]
Build was aborted
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

**UPDATE**

My Jenkins config execution shell is now

```
npm install protractor -g
npm install chromedriver -g
npm install
node_modules/protractor/node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update
ng e2e
ng build --prod
... docker build / docker push commands...
```

And then because it wasn't finding the chrome binary, I amended `protractor.conf.js`  to include the binary path to the global chromedriver, but it said not found still.

Also tried setting the binary path to the project level chromedriver (as seen below)

```
chromeOptions: {
  args: ["--headless"],
  binary: '/apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/blah/bleh/project_folder/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_75.0.3770.140'
}
```

but now the error message is

```
+ ng e2e
...
[34mℹ[39m [90m｢wdm｣[39m: Compiled successfully.
[11:45:31] I/update - chromedriver: file exists /apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/IT-CVC-Finance_and_Employee_Services/fina-ui-cae1/fina-ui1-Container/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_75.0.3770.140.zip
[11:45:31] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_75.0.3770.140.zip
[11:45:31] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/IT-CVC-Finance_and_Employee_Services/fina-ui-cae1/fina-ui1-Container/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_75.0.3770.140
[11:45:31] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_75.0.3770.140 up to date
[11:45:32] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:45:32] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[11:45:32] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/IT-CVC-Finance_and_Employee_Services/fina-ui-cae1/fina-ui1-Container/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_75.0.3770.140 is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=75.0.3770.90 (a6dcaf7e3ec6f70a194cc25e8149475c6590e025-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1003}),platform=Linux 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64 x86_64)
[11:45:32] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /apps/dftjenkins/jenkins_node/workspace/IT-CVC-Finance_and_Employee_Services/fina-ui-cae1/fina-ui1-Container/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_75.0.3770.140 is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
...
[11:45:32] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
An unexpected error occurred: undefined
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Comment: Have you checked inside your jenkins machine whether driver exists on the location? If not you have to run driver manager setting up command inside your jenkins box.

Comment: Is the Jenkins ChromeDriver plugin what I want? Found it here https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ChromeDriver+plugin

Comment: No need of installing Jenkins plugins. First forget about Jenkins and prepare your machine to run the protractor tests as you did on your local machine.

Comment: Do you mean `npm install protractor -g`, `npm install chromedriver -g`? Did that. But it still says chrome binary not found. Should i set the chrome binary path in **protractor.conf** to the global chromedriver, because I did, but maybe im using the wrong path (`apps/dftjenkins/local/nodeJS/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver`)? Or should i set the path to `node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_75.0.3770.140`? When i set the binary path to the project specific folder, it gives the error added above (updated my main post with that error).

Comment: As per updated post error message, Now Protractor can find the chrome driver but have issues with starting chrome. Few troubleshooting points 1. Make sure your browser and driver versions are matching 2.Make sure your chrome browser installed on default location 3. Jenkins user can start the chrome browser 4. Running with Headless chrome

Comment: Waiting on our support team to get back to me with help on this, but do you know how I can check for Chrome installation on this machine or install it if necessary? I don't have free access to it and can only run commands on it in my config execution shell. If I have chromedriver_75.0.3770.140, do I need Chrome 75? No other version (older or newer) would work?

Comment: Using the commends  chrome --version and ./chromedriver --version check installed version.  Check below for browser and driver version mapping https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/src/main/resources/versions.properties

Comment: it's simple.. get google chrome installed. it's the only way to pass this error as i had it ones

Answer (score 0):

My team has this setup on our jenkins CI server (granted isn't hosted in cloudbees but should be similar). The error implies that it can't find the chrome webdriver so things I would check:

- Check that Chrome is in fact installed
- Check that you have the appropriate webdriver driver installed you can get them here: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

There's likely more you'll have to do to get this completed but that is definitely where you'd start.